# How repair Dspace list by date?

Tags: dspace

I installed a dspace 6.3, and don´t work list by date the error is

```
Error in discovery while setting up date facet range:date facet\colon; dateIssued.year
org.dspace.discovery.SearchServiceException: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'dateIssued_keyword:[1960+TO+1969]': Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 32.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
    <RANGE_QUOTED> ...
    <RANGE_GOOP> ...
```

Any idea how repair this feature?

Comment: If you have access to the Solr console, you might be able to gather some information by looking at the dateIssued.year field.  /solr/#/search/schema-browser?field=dateIssued.year

Comment: This may be a difficult issue to resolve on StackOverflow.  You may want to see out the other support channels for DSpace.  https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Support

Comment: Did you try to update solr index?

Comment: I'm new at dspace, how i can update solr index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At dspace.cfg change the follow

```
webui.browse.index.1 = dateissued:metadata:dc.date.issued:date:full
```

At /usr/java/tomcat-9.0.13/webapps/jspui/WEB-INF/classes/Messages_es.properties add

```
browser.type.medata.dateissued = Fecha de publicación
```

And restart tomcat

Answer (score 0):

If you have built DSpace successfully, try updating solr index by running this command: 
`sudo sh [dspace]/bin/dspace index-discovery`
where [dspace] is the directory that DSpace is built in. For more information on this command click [here](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Discovery).
If your problem was not resolved, I suggest a complete rebuild of DSpace and running the above command afterward. I am on DSpace 5 and I use a script like the following one for a complete rebuild of DSpace and reindexing Solr. I hope it is useful for you as well:

```
cd [dspace-src]
sudo git pull
sudo  sh [tomcat]/bin/shutdown.sh
sleep 5

echo "---- Clean out old cache files ----"
sudo rm -R [tomcat]/work/Catalina/localhost/*
sudo rm -R [dspace]/log/*

echo "---- Clean out old webapps ----"
sudo rm -rf [dspace]/webapps/*

echo "---- Start MAVEN packaging ----"
cd [dspace-src]
mvn -U -e clean package

echo "---- Start ANT build ----"
cd [dspace-src]/dspace/target/dspace-installer/
sudo  ant fresh_install

echo "---- Remove old catalina log file ----"
sudo rm [tomcat]/logs/catalina.out
sleep 5

sudo cp -R [dspace]/webapps/* [tomcat]/webapps/
sleep 5
sudo  sh [tomcat]/bin/startup.sh
sleep 10
sudo sh [dspace]/bin/dspace index-discovery
```